# Change in a multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I´m covering a book on derivatives and I got stuck in the formula for the change of a two variable function:

$$f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b)=h\alpha+k\beta+\sqrt{k^2+h^2}\epsilon(h,k)$$

In which: $$\lim_{(k,h)\to (0,0)}\epsilon(h,k)=0$$

The book merely delivers this definition and states that a multivariable function is not differentiable if it doesn´t have this property. However, I tried to derive this using Pythagoras theorem and if we set some equalities to simplify the writing:

$$f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b)=\Delta f
$$
$$f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)=\Delta fx$$
$$f(a,b+k)-f(a,b)=\Delta fy$$
$$f(a+h,b+k)-f(a+h,b)=\Delta fy2$$
$$f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b+k)=\Delta fx2$$
And, considering $\theta$ to be the line connecting $f(a+h,b)$ and $f(a,b)$, $\zeta$ to be the one connecting $f(a+h,b+k)$ and $f(a,b)$, $\gamma$ to connect $f(a+h,b+k)$ and $f(a+h,b)$, $\eta$ to connect $f(a+h,b+k)$ and $f(a,b+k)$ and, at last, $\delta$ to connect $f(a,b+k)$ and $f(a,b)$, we can consider the following relationships between the greek letters:

$$\zeta^2=\theta^2+\gamma^2$$
$$\zeta^2=\delta^2+\eta^2$$

We can also estabilish the following:

$$\zeta^2=(\Delta f)^2+h^2+k^2$$
$$\theta^2=(\Delta fx)^2+h^2$$
$$\gamma^2=(\Delta fy2)^2+k^2$$
$$\delta^2=(\Delta fy)^2+k^2$$
$$\eta^2=(\Delta fx2)^2+h^2$$

But after applying this, what I get is:

$$(\Delta f)^2=(\Delta fx)^2+(\Delta fy2)^2=(\Delta fy)^2+(\Delta fx2)^2$$

Immediately we notice that this can't be true because obviously:

$$(\Delta f)=(\Delta fx)+(\Delta fy2)=(\Delta fy)+(\Delta fx2)$$

I'm sorry for all this mess, but i don't even think i'm taking the right route. I would very much appreciate any help in proving that formula, because I just can't move on without fully understanding it. Thank you.

Comment: You can't prove a definition. What the book states is the mere definition of a differentiable function. You can't prove it, unless you want to work with another definition of differentiability. Anyway, please do not confuse zero-order identites with their first-order approximations.

Comment: if we write $f(a+h,b+k)-f(a+h,b)+f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)$ may use mean value theorem for both $f(a+h,b+k)-f(a+h,b)$ and $f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)$ those are $f(a+h,b+k)-f(a+h,b)=f_y(a+h,\zeta)h$ and $f(a+h,b)-f(a,b)=f_x(\xi,b)h$.

Comment: But the definition should come from the one correspondent to a single variable function: $f(a+h)-f(a)=hf'(a)+h\epsilon (h)$, which one can derive, shouldn't it?

Comment: I understand. Then should I feel comfortable with it? Because i think it makes total sense, but it didn't feel ok without a proof...

Comment: Proof of that definition, because even knowing it is a definition, it feels provable.

Answer (score 0):

The book is adhering to the linearization of a function $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. For your case, $n = 2$ and $f$ is differentiable on $U$ with continuous partial derivatives. We can use taylor's formula for 1-variable and the chain-rule to get a linear approximation of $f|_{U}$ and this is that expression. I have more details here in my notes on page 19,20 ([notes](https://explorationsingeometry.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/differential-geometry-notes23.pdf)). There you'll see why that error bound decays the way they are supposing.